# Transforming Custom Object List into ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have a List weirdList that contains List, returned from a class method. However, I want it to be transformed into an ArrayList funkyArrayList that I can use to populate my ListView.

CrazyObject has methodX.toString, so I tried this:

```
weirdList = CrazyObject.findAll(); // returns List<CrazyObject>

for(CrazyObject c : weirdList) {
   funkyArrayList.add(c.methodX.toString);
}
```

In case weirdList would be empty, I would add a string myself:

```
if(weirdList.isEmpty) {
    funkyArrayList.add("nothing there");
}
```

Yet, the app crashed with no 'reason'. What am I doing wrong?
I am using the doInBackground() - which should't be the showstopper.

Comment: show us the complete code...

Comment: show us the complete code.

Comment: No parentheses after toString? That would add the toString method itself, not the value returned by calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `weirdList` a list of `Object`s:

```
private List<Object> weirdList = ArrayList<Object>();
```

Then you can initialize it with an array list of any objects you like:

```
weirdList = new ArrayList<Object>(CrazyObject.findAll()); //CrazyObject.findAll() returns ArrayList<CrazyObject>
```

and later use it with casts:

```
CrazyObject c = (CrazyObject)weirdList.get(index);
```

or for your loop:

```
for(Object o : weirdList) {
   CrazyObject c = (CrazyObject)o;
   funkyArrayList.add(c.methodX().toString());
}
```

Comment: I knew I had to do some sort of casting! Thanks!